# Spark extract value to multiple columns based on name

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

i have a String column and need to extract values of it into multiple columns based on the name associated with it.

```
otherPartofString State DALLocate_SFO-4/3/9 sub Area=<8> ID 8 Name 7
```

the columns need to be formed from above are

```
State     | Area      | Sub Area | ID | Name
DALLocate | SFO-4/3/9 | 8        | 8  | 7
```

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF the pattern is always fixed you could use regexp_extract:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_extract

df = spark.createDataFrame([{"raw": "otherPartofString State DALLocate_SFO-4/3/9 sub Area=<8> ID 8 Name 7 "}], 'raw string') 

(df
 .select(regexp_extract('raw', 'State ([^_]*)', 1).alias('State'), 
         regexp_extract('raw', 'State ([a-zA-Z]*)_([^ ]*)', 2).alias('Area'), 
         regexp_extract('raw', 'Area=<(.*)>', 1).alias('Sub Area'), 
         regexp_extract('raw', 'ID ([^ ]*)', 1).alias('ID'),
         regexp_extract('raw', 'Name ([^ ]*)', 1).alias('Name')).show())
```

`regexp_extract` takes 3 arguments the first ist the column you want to match on. the second is the pattern and the third is the group you want to extract.

ref: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_extract

Comment: thanks for the reply. I see this part regexp_extract('raw', 'State ([a-zA-Z]*)_([^ ]*)', 2).alias('Area'), is failing. my data will sometimes be of  'DALLocate_SFO-4/3/9' or 'DALLocate_SFO-4/3/9_DAX-10/3/3'.. in this case I need to take 'SFO-4/3/9_DAX-10/3/3' as its value. any guess on how to handle this

Comment: try ('State ([^_]*)_(.*) sub',2)

Comment: little help. I have a string with value like ' SFOLocate ID Expose Name 10 ID 3 Area 10 '. when I use your regex, it is considering ID=Expose. but it should be ID=3, if I extract with string and space. can you help. @Matt

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
def myFunc: String => Array[String] = s => Array(/* TODO parse the string as you wish */)
val myUDF = udf(myFunc)

df.withColumn("parsedInput", myUDF(df("input")))
  .select(
    $"parsedInput"(0).as("State"),
    $"parsedInput"(1).as("Area"),
    $"parsedInput"(2).as("Sub Area"),
    $"parsedInput"(3).as("ID"),
    $"parsedInput"(4).as("Name"))
```

Where 'input' is your original input (e.g. "otherPartofString State DALLocate_SFO-4/3/9 sub Area=<8> ID 8 Name 7 ").

Make sure your UDF returns a valid array (num of items and order)